# Safari sometimes doesnt center text horizontally

Tags: html, css, safari

I am trying to center text in photo. It works in chrome/mozilla perfectly, though there are problems with Safari.
Here are screenshots of the div from different browsers:

Safari:
[image: safari]

Chrome:
[image: chrome]

When page is refreshed on Safari the text is often centered.

I dont have any ideas how to fix that.

HTML:

```
<div id="giftsHeaderPhoto" class="akcija">
  <div class="subCategoryName">
    <h1 > Grožis </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="intro_block">
    <div class="intro_text">
      <div class="intro_text-short">
        <span>{$intro_text}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="intro_text-buttonBox">
         <span class="buttonShowMore">Plačiau</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

SCSS:

```
#giftsHeaderPhoto {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    background-size: 1920px 350px;
    background-position: center top;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    &::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        transition: background-color 0.3s;
    }
    &:hover::after {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        transition: background-color 0.3s;
    }
    .subCategoryName {
        width:80%;
        margin: auto;
        padding-top: 80px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        color:rgba(white, 0.8);
        text-align:center;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all 300ms;
        letter-spacing: 15px;
        h1 {
            font-weight: 1000;
            color: white;
        }
```

Expected behaviour: subCategoryName class is always centered in any browser.

Outcome: subCategoryName class is more to the right in Safari sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Add the property

```
margin: auto;
```

to the container div ie, the parent div where all your sub divisions are contained.

also provide,

```
text-align: center;
```

to the actual element to be centered.

if nothing works, a `<center>...</center>` tag may help.

You can also refer [this link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23446665/CSS-text-align-center-doesn't-work-in-Safari.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
        body {
            margin: 0px;
        }
        #giftsHeaderPhoto {
            width: 100%;
            height: 350px;
            background-size: 1920px 350px;
            background-position: center top;
            background-color: white;
            margin-top: 0px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        #giftsHeaderPhoto::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            transition: background-color 0.3s;
        }
        #giftsHeaderPhoto:hover::after {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            transition: background-color 0.3s;
        }
        .subCategoryName {
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding-top: 80px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
            color: rgba(white, 0.8);
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: all 300ms;
            letter-spacing: 15px;
        }
        h1 {
            font-weight: 1000;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .intro_block {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

```html
<div id="giftsHeaderPhoto" class="akcija">
        <div class="subCategoryName">
            <h1> Grožis </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="intro_block">
            <div class="intro_text">
                <div class="intro_text-short">
                    <span>{$intro_text}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="intro_text-buttonBox">
                    <span class="buttonShowMore">Plačiau</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```